# How to completely remove Python from a Windows machine?

Tags: python, installation, uninstallation

I installed both Python 2.7 and Python 2.6.5. I don't know what went wrong, but nothing related to Python seems to work any more. e.g. "setup.py install" for certain packages don't recognize the "install" parameter and other odd phenomena...

I would like to completely remove Python from my system.
I tried running the 2.7 and 2.6 msi files and choosing remove Python and then running only 2.6 and reinstalling it. Still stuff don't work.

How do I completely remove Python - from everything? (!)

I would not like to reinstall my entire machine just because of the Python install...

Comment: I've discovered that the "odd phenomena" occurred due to a 3rd python installation that was installed without my notice by a buildout script...

Comment: The trick appears to be figuring out where a particular installation came from. In my case, I have two that are not from chocolatey, pip, or the control panel. Trying to figure out what else might have done it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You will also have to look in your system path. Python puts itself there and does not remove itself: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Your problems probably started because your python path is pointing to the wrong one.

Comment: And you may have to cleanup the Windows Registry to remove the Registry Key that's there.  See this http://effbot.org/zone/python-register.htm and this: http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#finding-modules

Comment: I'm flagging this as the answer as this is closest to what my problem was... I found out that my .py association was changed by a buildout installation of python. This is why it seemed I couldn't get Python out of my system - I actually had a hidden installation inside one of the projects...

Comment: Actually, all my python files were kept where they were installed. Also, all package data created in the users folder were also kept.

Answer (score 67):

Here's the steps (my non-computer-savvy girlfriend had to figure this one out for me, but unlike all the far more complicated processes one can find online, this one works)

1. Open Control Panel
2. Click "Uninstall a Program"
3. Scroll down to Python and click uninstall for each version you don't want anymore.

This works on Windows 7 out of the box, no additional programs or scripts required.

Comment: If you installed files with `pip`, you may want to remove its cache in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\pip`

Comment: Did this, and after uninstalling I only had 19784 files and 495 MB left in the Python installation folder. Impressive...

Comment: This is not enough in most cases as user136036 mentioned

Comment: uninstalling all python interpreters (I had many versions ranging from 3.7 to 3.10) and leaving only one solved the issue for me. Pip worked normally afterwards and detected imports. Im on windows 10

Answer (score 41):

you can delete it manually.

1. open Command Prompt
2. `cd C:\Users\<you name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`
3. `del python.exe`
4. `del python3.exe`

Now the command prompt won't be showing it anymore

`where python` --> yields nothing, and you are free to install another version from source / anaconda and (after adding its address to Environment Variables -> Path) you will find that very python you just installed

Comment: You can also use `cd %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps`, which should be the right path even if the system partition has a drive letter other than `C:`.

Comment: I can see the files there, but I can't delete them...

Comment: I was only able to delete it from the powershell prompt as admin. Windows explorer gave me an error.

Comment: The "only able to delete it from the powershell prompt as admin" is critical piece of information. I had the same problem as rocksNwaves trying to do it from the Explorer, but not from a shell.

Answer (score 14):

Run ASSOC and FTYPE to see what your py files are associated to.  (These commands are internal to cmd.exe so if you use a different command processor ymmv.)

```
C:> assoc .py
.py=Python.File

C:> ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Python26.w64\python.exe" "%1" %*

C:> assoc .pyw
.pyw=Python.NoConFile

C:> ftype Python.NoConFile
Python.NoConFile="C:\Python26.w64\pythonw.exe" "%1" %*
```

(I have both 32- and 64-bit installs of Python, hence my local directory name.)

Comment: -1: none of my consoles recognize this command. Please provide references for how you obtained it.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: a quick search on Google should show you that they are part of Windows. I don't know when they were introduced but I seem to remember them being there as a part of WinXP and they are a part of Win7, although perhaps they're left out of some editions; I'm not terribly knowledgeable about Windows edition differences).

Comment: Nor am I, nor is anyone else, I don't think. I have two computers running Windows 7... I forget what edition, but neither of them have any of those commands.

Comment: Curious, I looked it up. `ftype` and `assoc` are internal to cmd.exe. Perhaps you're using a third party command processor that doesn't support the full command set?  http://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html

Comment: I attempted to use cmd just now and it found the commands. I had been using power shell as I was under the impression it did everything cmd did and more. My apologies. I have undone my downvote.

Comment: Just a note - this also works with the TCmd shell.

Answer (score 10):

1. Open CMD
2. To show all packages installed - `pip list`
3. To copy the packages name to a file - `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
4. To delete all packages - `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y`
5. Check all packages are removed - `pip list`
6. Uninstall pip and other remaining packages
7. Control panel > Uninstall > Python uninstall (from UI)

Comment: "7. uninstall other remaining packages" how? when everything is uninstalled and list shows empty already?

Comment: @user8395964 if the list shows more packages, you can uninstall them as well, otherwise its fine.

Answer (score 9):

I had window 7 (64 bit) and Python 2.7.12, 
I uninstalled it by clicking the python installer from the "download" directory then  I selected remove python then I clicked “ finish”.
I also removed the remaining python associated directory & files from the c: drive and also from “my documents” folder, since I created some files there.

Comment: If you don't still have the Python installer, download it again and that'll give you access to the Uninstall option. I found in Windows 10 that the Add/Remove Programs uninstall facility didn't uninstall, but the Python installer did allow me to.

Answer (score 8):

First, uninstall Python, then remove the pip packages you installed.

- Uninstall Python: `"Add or Remove Programs"`, search for Python and uninstall it.
- Remove Pip packages: type in File Explorer `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python`, and remove the folders you want.

This will clean up any pip package you installed. Otherwise, if you were to reinstall Python, you will find yourself with the same pip packages that you had.

Answer (score 5):

It's actually quite simple.
When you installed it, you must have done it using some .exe file (I am assuming). Just run that .exe again, and then there will be options to modify Python. Just select the "Complete Uninstall" option, and the EXE will completely wipe out python for you.

Also, you might have to checkbox the "Remove Python from PATH". By default it is selected, but you may as well check it to be sure :)

Comment: I had to give the command line prompt /uninstall for 3.9.0 to uninstall, but that did work. The windows add/remove did NOT - Python wasn't even listed.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall the python program using the windows GUI.
Delete the containing folder e.g if it was stored in `C:\python36\` make sure to delete that folder

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an old question, but I ran into this problem with 2.7 and 3.5. Though 2.7 would not show up in my default windows uninstall list, it showed up fine in the ccleaner tools tab under uninstall. Uninstalled and reinstalled afterwards and it has been smooth coding ever since.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the python installer on your PC, you can double-click on it (run it, it will open the installer window), and select the "Uninstall" option. It will uninstall that python version (if the installer is for Python3.9, then Python3.9 will be uninstalled, if it is for Python3.10, then that version...)

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of the python files should live in their respective folders (`C:\Python26` and `C:\Python27`).  Some installers (ActiveState) will also associate `.py*` files and add the python path to `%PATH%` with an install if you tick the "use this as the default installation" box.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 64-bit, with both Python3.4 and Python2.7 installed at some point :)

I'm using Py.exe to route to Py2 or Py3 depending on the script's needs - but I previously improperly uninstalled Python27 before.

Py27 was removed manually from C:\python\Python27 (the folder Python27 was deleted by me previously)

Upon re-installing Python27, it gave the above error you specify.
It would always back out while trying to 'remove shortcuts' during the installation process.

I placed a copy of Python27 back in that original folder, at C:\Python\Python27, and re-ran the same failing Python27 installer.  It was happy locating those items and removing them, and proceeded with the install.

This is not the answer that addresses registry key issues (others mention that) but it is somewhat of a workaround if you know of previous installations that were improperly removed.

You could have some insight to this by opening "regedit" and searching for "Python27" - a registry key appeared in my command-shell Cache pointing at c:\python\python27\ (which had been removed and was not present when searching in the registry upon finding it).

That may help point to previously improperly removed installations.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Windows Start Menu > Settings > Apps > Apps & features > Select the app and click the Uninstall button

Answer (score -3):

install IObit uninstaller it will completely remove Python.