# Enthought Canopy: 'pythonw.exe has stopped working'

Tags: python-2.7, enthought, canopy, pythonw

I am currently running Enthought Canopy version 1.5.2 full version, through an academic license at a 64bit Windows 7. I was a happy user for a couple months until a 'pythonw.exe has stopped working' issue rendered the software useless. This issue shows up when I open the editor (Ipython+Canopy's GUI) and does not allows me to use the software at all. I have tried the following solutions without luck:

- Fresh install deleting several folders manually (https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469700-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy)
- Fresh install+clearing python registry keys under hkeys_user and hkey_system and pythonw.exe related keys into windows regedit.exe ([Problems in fully uninstalling Python 2.7 from Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828294/problems-in-fully-uninstalling-python-2-7-from-windows-7))

My second try actually gave me a false sense of victory, when Canopy worked for a couple hours, until the same issue happened taking all hope with it.

I don't know what to do anymore, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Was it Canopy 1.5.2 that worked well for you for a couple of months, or a previous version? Reinstalling will probably make no difference since it's unlikely to be corrupted. When you say "deleting several files" do you mean that you deleted all three directories Canopy and User and System? Did you install any other Python-related software on your system around the time that the problems began?

Comment: Thanks for your attention.
Yes, that is what I meant with "deleting several files". I did not install anything python-related except for updates through Canopy (packages and software). Now that you pointed out, I did have 1.5.1 before and I don't know when I updated to 1.5.2 so that could be it. Although I did not correlate any updates with the problems when they began I will give the downgrade a shot.

Comment: I was just gathering context, not suggesting a downgrade, as that's unlikely to help. (If you **do**, be sure to delete **all** those directories after uninstalling and before reinstalling.) First I would try disabling your 3rd-party anti-virus software (if any) and relying instead on Microsoft's, as many such utilities find false positives, especially in a collection of files as huge as your full Canopy installation.

Comment: Speaking of which, there's really no reason to install the full installer if you have an internet connection; your academic license allows you to download packages as needed rather than cluttering with 250 packages that you'll never use, occupying 3 GB and 10s of thousands of files.

Comment: Ok, I did not downgrade and disabled the Panda antivirus to run canopy but the problem persists (I also noticed one quarantined file that is definitely not python related). You are right, there is no need for me to run a full installation. I just started using python a few months ago and had no idea what I would use that is why I downloaded the full version. Any other ideas? 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also. And discovered it was due to my windows firewall blocking pythonw.exe

Either turn off the firewall. Or create exceptions for pythonw.exe (but be warned this files occurs in a few different directories. And I'm not sure which one gave the specific issue.

In the end I installed a new firewall (COMODO). And now everything works...