# How to completely uninstall Python 2.7 from Windows 7 PC

Tags: python, installation, uninstallation

Having installed Python 2.7 from here:

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/

I then uninstalled it using the control panel (I have Windows 7 pro). Now Python 2.7 no longer appears in the list of installed programs, however the files are still sitting in the same place on the `C:` drive.

I have since installed version 2.6 but I seem to be having some clashing issues between the versions. I'm having similar issues to this guy:

[How to completely remove Python from a Windows machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515673/how-to-completely-remove-python-from-a-windows-machine)

I just want to know how can I remove Python 2.7 completely?

Will simply deleting the folders from my `C:` drive be sufficient?

How can I test that it has been completely removed?

Comment: Also remove Python path from `PATH` environment variable, if you have not already done.

Comment: Deleting the directory you've installed python inside has worked for me when I was replacing Python 2.7 with Python 3.4

Comment: Have you uninstall it from the program uninstall menu?

Comment: No I used the control panel programs and features to do it. Perhaps I should have used the uninstall from the program menu but unfortunately that is not an option now.

Comment: Can you run the following line on a cmd windows `python -c "print 1+1"` ? If you cannot , it is ok. If you can, python is still installed.

Comment: Try the command line I gave you. Then if things are fine, go for manual deletion.

Comment: Hi Andy but python is still installed I have version 2.6 installed this is the version that is called when I try your code on the command line. Is it better just to remove everything and start over?

Comment: To be clear it printed 2

Comment: indeed @Bazman. If I were you, I would remove everything then reinstall the version of python you want to install.

Answer (score 8):

You should just be able to delete the local files if you've already uninstalled from control panel. Also be sure to go to your environment variables and make sure that the python 2.7 directory isn't there. To do that,

- Go to the start menu and right click on Computer
- Click on Properties
- Advanced system settings
- Environment Variables and look for "path" under system variables
- Be sure to erase `C:\...\Python2.7.x`

If you uninstalled from control panel it might not be there but it's probably good to double check. Also, be sure to delete the `;` before `C:\...\Python2.7.x`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I kept installing Python 3.6 but when I typed "python" from the command prompt, Python 2.7 kept opening up despite the fact that I had uninstalled and it wasn't in my Path or in my Programs folder. I eventually solved the problem by uninstalling Enthought/Canopy from my computer and also erasing all the related files. Now I have a regular installation of Python 3.6 working and accessible from the command prompt. I assume I could now also get a parallel python 2.7 going, but I haven't tried to since I have no need for it at the moment.
The giveaway for me that my python 2.7 installation was strange was that when I typed:

```
python --version
```

into the command prompt, I was getting the following:

```
Python 2.7.6 -- CUSTOM
```