# Script works in shell but not as IDLE file

Tags: python, shell, command-line, eof

When the following code is executed line by line on shell, it is giving the expected output :

```
>>> name=input("Please give your full name : ")
Please give your full name : ins vikranth
>>> ListName=name.split(' ')
>>> outputString=ListName[1]+' '+ListName[0]
>>> print(outputString)
vikranth ins
```

The code is not running in total as a file but runs line by line on the shell. 
The code is :

```
name=input("Please give your full name : ")
ListName=name.split(' ')
outputString=ListName[1]+' '+ListName[0]
print(outputString)
```

The error message is :

```
Please give your full name : ins vikranth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ReverseName.py", line 1, in <module>
    name=input("Please give your full name
  File "<string>", line 1
    ins vikranth
               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your code works for me (Python 3.7.2), without error. How are you running the file `ReverseName.py`?

Comment: Well, I might be missing something, but it is not reproductible on my side, how do you launch it?

Comment: `unexpected EOF while parsing` means there is a string that is not quoted properly. Are you not missing a `"` on the `input()` row ?

Comment: @adrianus I ran the program as $python ReverseName.py and got the error. This time I tried $python3 Reversename.py and everything went fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason why this is happening is your python version ... your IDLE is `python 3.X` while your file is being "translated" ( Interpret ) using `python 2.X` ... so there are 2 simple solutions:

1/ stick with `python 3.X` - your code is not going to change, just change Interpreter

2/ edit it to be compatible with `python 2.X` :

```
name=raw_input("Please give your full name : ")
```

also here are 2 online compilers, where you can see the difference:

Python 3.7 -> https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler

Python 2.7 -> https://repl.it/languages/python

Comment: Python does not compile

Comment: i know ... I just wasnt sure how to write it ... thts why i put it in a " "

Comment: I think `interpreted` is fine :)

Comment: @StyleZ pease let me know how can I update my interpreter to 3.x as is the shell.

Comment: delete python 2.7 <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723607/how-to-completely-uninstall-python-2-7-from-windows-7-pc?rq=1> and then normally install python 3.7 <https://realpython.com/installing-python/>
or you can do something like this: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786478/how-to-run-different-python-versions-in-cmd>

Comment: @StyleZ, Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

@Babu brother code seems to okey for me but you might forget somepoint.If person have a middle name it will cause an error. You have 2 array locations when user types more than 2 words it cause an unexpected end of file due to lack of location like Kevin Prince Boateng a footballer. You might want to look  this https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html for a dynamical memory management

Comment: my code is accepting 4 words and giving output as expected.                                                $Please give your full name : abc pqr xyz lmn>>
lmn xyz xyz abc

Comment: name=input("Please give your full name : ")
ListName=name.split(' ')
outputString=ListName[3]+' '+ListName[2]+' '+ListName[2]+' '+ListName[0]
print(outputString)
@A.Toraman