# How to uninstall Python and all packages

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, package, anaconda

I wish to uninstall Python 2.7 and all packages connected to it. I initially installed Python from the official website and I installed all packages using the pip install command. Would uninstalling Python from the control panel also uninstall all packages automatically?

The reason I want to uninstall Python is because I want to use Anaconda in order to be able to manage packages more easily and also be able to install both Python 2 and 3 to switch between them back and forth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely remove Python from a Windows machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515673/how-to-completely-remove-python-from-a-windows-machine)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you uninstall from the control panel, it should remove all packages with it.  To ensure that your path doesn't contain your old python when you try and use anaconda, you should remove Python from your path. In windows 10:

1. From desktop go bottom left and find the menu.
2. Click system, then Advanced System Settings
3. In this window, go to the Advanced tab and click on the environment variables button.
4. From there you can edit your Path, with the edit button.
5. Make sure there is no reference to Python here.  Also, all variables are separated by a ; so make sure all syntax is good before saving.
6. Install anaconda and at the end of the install it should ask if you want to make it the default Python.  Say yes and every time you or another program asks for Python, it will get pointed to anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

What I was able to do is use the Set-up executable which installed Python. It gave me the options Install or Repair or Uninstall.
Then I went to my Environmental Variables.
I delete Python from my list of Paths.