# how to completely remove Python and all its libraries

Tags: python

I am having problem with python and would like to remove completely so I can install it again

I went to Add remove programs and  uninstalled Coda Python and Python 3.8 that I already have

I thought by doing that I uninstalled it successfully

but after I install it again I found that all libraries already there and having same problems

I tried uninstall libraries through `pip unistall tensorflow-gpu` but python is stuck there and does nothing, I left my computer over night and still nothing happened.

So How to remove everything and start green field?

Comment: Is your problem with a particular library or with a version of Python?

Comment: I want to remove python regardless of the proble

Comment: Which is your operating system?

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: usually, once you have removed the program/do restart on the PC it should all go away. if not the case, double check the environment variables don't still show the old python paths (you can remove those and try again).

Comment: @FishingCode even if the env variable not removed the folder of the library should be removed but actually non of these is removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this as an alternative solution. It's a more graceful removal of libraries

```
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

In case you have packages installed via VCS, you need to exclude those lines and remove the packages manually (elevated from the comments below):

```
pip freeze | grep -v "^-e" | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Comment: I want to know how to remove python and all its libraries

Comment: check out this [link](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-uninstall-python)

Comment: This is what I did aand ended with libraries already installed

Comment: you can also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324425/how-to-uninstall-python-and-all-packages)

Comment: I did that too, libraries still there

Comment: OK here I got another one for you hope will work [this one](https://intellipaat.com/community/4905/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip)