# How to uninstall python?

Tags: python

I had uninstalled python 3.10 because I want to run python 3.7.5
so I uninstalled all and there is no python folder or files in C drive.
but the registry have lots of python files and I don't know how to clean up this all files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall Python and all packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324425/how-to-uninstall-python-and-all-packages)

Comment: Linux, Mac, Windows, OpenBSD, Solaris...? I guess you mean Windows

Comment: Why not just use a `virtualenv`?

Comment: yes it's windows

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments above has shown you the correct way to uninstall any version of Python.

If you have to use multiple versions of Python, it's recommended to use a version manager. Some good choices are [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) and [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win).