# Jupyter notebook starting error - Win7 64Bit [anaconda2 4.4.0 ]

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, pyzmq

I'm new to anaconda ,After fresh anaconda 4.4.0 on win 7 64bit
I get the following crash:

```
(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2) C:\Users\LordTitiKaka>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import notebook.notebookapp
  File "C:\Users\LordTitiKaka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", lin
e 32, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\LordTitiKaka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 34, in
 <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\LordTitiKaka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", lin
e 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\LordTitiKaka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", lin
e 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\LordTitiKaka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line
26, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\LordTitiKaka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.p
y", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I've tried re-installing pyzmq also removed any previous python2.7 installation 
this is without any effect

How can it be fixed ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19019720/1951298

Comment: Just install the 32-bit version of Python2.7. You may have to re-install Jupyter and reset Environment variables, currently is trying to load a **none 32-bit** version of the DLL

Comment: @EnriqueBruzual did that(install py2.7 32bit) + remove/add of pyzmq + jupyter , no change in error . how can make the conda point to the right python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[after looking on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515673/how-to-completely-remove-python-from-a-windows-machine) I understood that I need to find any remnants of python on my PC and delete it

I've remove anaconda and re-install : **did not work**

remove all Python installation and re-install : **did not work**

than I figured it may look for some local packages , so I've removed all Python related under roaming : **worked**