# Unable to uninstall Python 3.6 (32 bit)

Tags: windows, python-3.x, uninstallation

Python 3.6 (32 bit) is installed on my computer in Program file folder. And it is available as a shortcut in my start menu. But I do not see it in "Control Panel --> Program and Features". So I am unable to uninstall it. Is there any other way (like, command line) to uninstall Python?

I have to uninstall the 32 bit. Then I have to re-install 64-bit version please.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515673/how-to-completely-remove-python-from-a-windows-machine)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the installation file like will setup.
2. When the installation window open, you can see "Change", "Repair" and "Remove".
3. Select "Remove" and continue.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

1. Open the installation file as admin.
2. Select Uninstall.