# Numpy module not found when working with Azure Functions in VS Code and virtualenv

Tags: python, numpy, azure-functions, virtualenv

I'm new to working with azure functions and tried to work out a small example locally, using VS Code with the Azure Functions extension.

Example:

```
# First party libraries
import logging

# Third party libraries
import numpy as np
from azure.functions import HttpResponse, HttpRequest


def main(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    seed = req.params.get('seed')

    if not seed:
        try:
            body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            seed = body.get('seed')

    if seed:
        np.random.seed(seed=int(seed))
        r_int = np.random.randint(0, 100)
        logging.info(r_int)
        return HttpResponse(
            "Random Number: " f"{str(r_int)}", status_code=200
            )
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            "Insert seed to generate a number",
            status_code=200
            )
```

When numpy is installed globally this code works fine. If I install it only in the virtual environment, however, I get the following error:

```
*Worker failed to function id 1739ddcd-d6ad-421d-9470-327681ca1e69.
[15-Jul-20 1:31:39 PM] Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'. Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound*
```

I checked multiple times that numpy is installed in the virtual environment, and the environment is also specified in the .vscode/settings.json file.

pip freeze of the virtualenv "worker_venv":

```
$ pip freeze
azure-functions==1.3.0
flake8==3.8.3
importlib-metadata==1.7.0
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.19.0
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pyflakes==2.2.0
zipp==3.1.0
```

.vscode/settings.json file:

```
{
  "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
  "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
  "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": "worker_venv",
  "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
  "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~2",
  "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

I tried to find something in the documentation, but found nothing specific regarding the virtual environment. I don't know if I'm missing something?

EDIT: I'm on a Windows 10 machine btw

EDIT: I included the folder structure of my project in the image below

[image]

EDIT: Added the content of the virtual environment Lib folder in the image below

[image]

EDIT: Added a screenshot of the terminal using the `pip install numpy` command below

[image]

EDIT: Created a new project with a new virtual env and reinstalled numpy, screenshot below, problem still persists.

[image]

EDIT: Added the launch.json code below

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9091,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
    }
  ]
}
```

**SOLVED**

So the problem was neither with python, nor with VS Code. The problem was that the execution policy on my machine (new laptop) was set to restricted and therefore the `.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1` script could not be run.

To resolve this problem, just open powershell with admin rights and and run `set-executionpolicy remotesigned`. Restart VS Code and all should work fine

I didn't saw the error, due to the many logging in the terminal that happens
when you start azure. I'll mark the answer of @HuryShen as correct, because the comments got me to the solution. Thank all of you guys

Comment: Do you have numpy included in requirements.txt? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#package-management

Comment: Yeah I included it in requirements.txt

Comment: Everything looks good to me. I have run into similar mysterious problems in the past and resolved them by re-creating everything in a new directory. Kind of like the 'ol "restart your computer" trick that fixes mysterious computer problems. Maybe give that a try?

Comment: @Tyson Tried as you and suggested, still doesn't work

Comment: Darn :(. I don't think this will fix your problem, but something else you could try is replacing "import numpy as np" with "from . import numpy as np"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this problem, I'm not clear if you met the error when run it locally or on azure cloud. So provide both suggestions for these two situation.

**1.** If the error shows when you run the function on azure, you may not have installed the modules success. When deploy the function from local to azure, you need to add the module to `requirements.txt`(as Anatoli mentioned in comment). You can generate the `requirements.txt` automatically by the command below:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

After that, we can find the `numpy==1.19.0` exist in `requirements.txt`.
[image]

Now, deploy the function from local to azure by the command below, it will install the modules success on azure and work fine on azure.

```
func azure functionapp publish <your function app name> --build remote
```

**2.** If the error shows when you run the function locally. Since you provided the modules installed in `worker_venv`, it seems you have installed `numpy` module success. I also test it in my side locally, install `numpy` and it works fine. So I think you can check if your virtual environment(`worker_venv`) exist in the correct location. Below is my function structure in local VS code, please check if your virtual environment locates in the same location with mine.

[image]

-----**Update**------

Run the command to to set execution policy and then activate the virtual environment:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I run into this problem locally on my windows 10 machine. I checked my folder structure and it looks the same to me as yours. I'll include the image in my previous post.

Comment: @CuriousFly And could you please share a screenshot of your Terminal window (with the pip install command) ?

Comment: @CuriousFly Can you show the content of Lib folder under your virtual environment? does the module be there?

Comment: @CuriousFly Could you please create another new project to develop your function because the old one may have some problem after many modification. Try again in the new project, and share a screenshot of "Terminal" window with the pip install command.

Comment: I added the content of the lib folder in the main post

Comment: @HuryShen I created a new project and reinstalled numpy in the new virtual environment, added the screenshots in the main post, problem still persists.

Comment: @CuriousFly Try run `func host start` directly under the virtual environment. Still get error?

Comment: @CuriousFly It seems everything is ok, may I know how did you run/start the function ? Could you please share a screenshot of the command to run the function ?

Comment: @BowmanZhu Ok, so when I run in with `func host start` it works fine, no errors. Is there a problem with VS Code?

Comment: @CuriousFly So it should be the problem with the vs code, it doesn't run function host under the virtual environment.

Comment: @HuryShen I tried to debug it through VS Code by pressing F5

Comment: @CuriousFly When you press F5, it will not use the modules installed in virtual environment.

Comment: @CuriousFly Please give us the settings.json in .vscode.

Comment: @BowmanZhu the settings.json file can be seen in the main post, I also added the launch.json file content

Comment: @HuryShen So is there a possibility to debug the code and us the modules installed in the virtual environment?

Comment: @CuriousFly Could you please share a screenshot of Terminal window after press F5 ? When I press F5, it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTniV.png). So it can run with virtual environment when I debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my issue uninstalling python3 (see here for a guide https://stackoverflow.com/a/60318668/11986067).

After starting the app functions via F5 or `func start`, the following output was shown:

[image]

This version was incorrect. I have chosen python 3.7.0 when creating the project in the Azure extension. After deleting this python3 version, the correct version was shown and the Import issue was solved:

[image]