# Python 3.8.0 Setup Failed - 0x80070666 Another version of this product is already installed / No Python installation detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, uninstallation, python-3.8

I installed 3.8.7, the dependencies didn't match up with the project I was trying so I uninstalled 3.8.7 and wanted to try 3.8.0. I get this error every time.

Things I've tried:

- Using Windows "Remove apps and programs". Doing this results in an error "No python 3.8 installation was found", an incredibly frustrating contradiction.
- Trying everything from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3515928/8142044), including removing environment variable paths, deleting registry `\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore3.8` (it was only there for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and wasn't there for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`)
- Tried uninstalling 3.8.7 with my 3.8.7 installation .exe, which brings up a "Modify Setup" screen (so it recognizes an installation somehow), but clicking uninstall brings up an error "No Python 3.8 installation was detected." I also tried the "Repair" option, which gives the same error. Choosing the "Modify" option shows me where another installation was (on my OS hard drive) that I deleted, and then ultimately going through with the modify process resulted in the same error as the other two options.

Every time I run a Python uninstallation it recreates the registry keys and the folders, but in the OS drive where none of my installations are. I can't direct the uninstallation program to uninstall from another path.

I'm thinking it's a combination of choosing my own installation paths (which is almost always never worth the trouble it causes) and the fact that my Python paths are not on my OS drive.

Comment: I am having the same issue here with Python 3.9.6.  I have 3.8.1, 3.9.7, and 3.10.0 all installed, but cannot install 3.9.6, I get the same error dialog.  I wish the python installer team would clean things up when a new version is installed and provide a harmonious way for multiple versions of python to exist on a system.

Comment: @user10664542 - unfortunately my only solution was to download the Windows Store version of Python

Comment: If it is not essential for your purposes then install Python for another Architecture. I'd had the same problem with Python 3.7.4 x86-64, so I successfully installed Python 3.7.4 x86 32-bit version.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, do the follwoing:

1. Modify your installation

- go to Settings -> Apps
- search for pyton 3.8
- click on modify instate of unistall
- execute the modification with default settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcMEW.png)

2. Reinstall python

- use the installer and install python again

Comment: OP mentioned "Using Windows 'Remove apps and programs' results in an error"

Comment: I mentioned to use the modfiy option instead of remove or uninstall then modfiy the current version in order to uninstall or remove it correctly afterwards