# Python modulenotfound in cmd

Tags: python

I'm new to python and when I tried to update pip in cmd this appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\pytong\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "d:\pytong\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\pytong\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
```

Now it pops up anytime I'm trying to do anything.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please put some more details in your question, such as what distribution of Python you are running? I'm assuming you are running this on a Windows 10 machine. Is that correct?

Comment: how you are trying to update pip?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to reinstall python or follow this - [How to completely remove Python from a Windows machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18430403/14901631)

After that restart your PC and install python from python webiste.