# IDLE and PyCharm are using different versions of python, despite the python.exe PyCharm is using being installed in the same directory

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, python-idle, arcpy

I cloned a python environment and recreated it on a new machine using Anaconda Navigator with a yml file. My script runs fine in the new environment using PyCharm. The python version of this environment is 3.9.0. However the script doesn't run with IDLE because IDLE is running version 3.11.0.

IDLE is located at:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\CloneETL3\Lib\idlelib\idle.pat

The python interpreter which PyCharm uses is located at

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\CloneETL3\python.exe

How can IDLE have a different version from the python interpreter when they were just installed fresh? How can I prevent multiple versions of python from running on my machine? I made sure to create a new project in PyCharm, use an existing interpreter using conda and point it to the exe I described above.

The environment was first created from a clone of my ArcGIS Pro environment.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can have as many versions as you like and select which one you desire at the point of execution....

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common in most editors. I use `vscode` which is similar to `pycharm` and the user can select the version of python (or other languages) that they wish to run.

It look like this:

[image]

The reason for this is that some users have the requirement of being compatible with previous versions. You should be able to select the latest version of each.

Alternatively you can delete all versions leaving **only the one version** that you desire, this would avoid confusion...

You could refer to this answer for that option: [How to completely remove Python from a Windows machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515673/how-to-completely-remove-python-from-a-windows-machine)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still having the issue that the python interpreter I run in PyCharm is version 3.9.11. When I open it with the version of Idle in the same environment, it tries to run in 3.9.15 and fails. Removing all versions of python will not work because I'm using an environment cloned from ArcGIS Pro. ArcGIS must have a version of python so I cannot uninstall it. Is there a way to change the version of Idle to the correct version? Thanks./